# How to check if the app is preloaded or installed from Windows Phone marketplace

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have an application which microsoft is preloading in some devices. I want to give offers to those users who are using these preloaded apps. But how can i distinguish if the app is preloaded or installed from marketplace on that device?

Comment: Wouldn't you just ask MS to preload a specific version, or preload specific save data into your iso storage...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Phone Extended properties https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties(v=vs.105).aspx

There is a property IsApplicationPreInstalled using this one can find if the application is preinstalled or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you use WP Silverlight you can do this by 2 ways:
 1. By version: you can parse your application page in store and get current version of your app then compare store version with app's version.
 2. By specific file: you can check file which added only in published packages: `System.IO.File.Exists("WMAppPRHeader.xml");`

Regards.